# Autogenerated code (designer.cs) error message: "This member has been defined more than once"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I create an entity on the Entity Framework designer surface and define the scalar properties, the message "This member has been defined more than once" is displayed from the designer.cs file  then compiler underlines "Id", "FirstName", "Title" etc. Can someone please help me. Below is a segment of the designer.cs code.

```
public static Employee CreateEmployee(global::System.Int32 id, global::System.String    firstName, global::System.String title, global::System.DateTime dateOfBirth, global::System.String userName, global::System.String password)
{
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.Id = id;
    employee.FirstName = firstName;
    employee.Title = title;
    employee.DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    employee.UserName = userName;
    employee.Password = password;
    return employee;
}
```

Comment: Show us all of the code from the designer file.

Comment: Well, the method is static. I guess that the first time you don't get this error. And after that you get it every time. Is that right?

Comment: Leron, I can't see how that could be the reason. This is a compile time issue. OP: Is it possible you renamed your context at some point and have an old designer file hanging around in the solution?